# MIPS: is it possible to overwrite certain words of a file?

Tags: mips

Is it possible to overwrite a file using MIPS?
I have a file and, under certain conditions (i.e. a user decide to update his personal data or delete completely) I need to delete/overwrite some words or row of the text file I have.
I tried this thing:
I already know how to find which word I would like to replace and, with a store byte i write on a buffer the "new" word.
Then I should save it on file. And that's where my problems begin since, using flag 1 (on syscall 13) overwrites the whole file and flag 9 doesn't apply any change. Here's my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
loop:    
la $t6, empty_space
sb $t6, buffer($s7)
beq $s7, $t5, save_on_file
subi $s7, $s7, 1
j loop

save_on_file:

#open file
li $v0, 13
la $a0, file_out
li $a1, 1
li $a2, 0
syscall
move $s6, $v0

#write on file
li $v0, 15
move $a0, $s6
la $a1, buffer
move $a2, $s7
syscall

#close
li $v0, 16
move $a0, $s6
syscall

j menu
```

Comment: Are you using MARS simulator ?. The `syscall` reference in MARS clearly states that you can only open a file in read_only/create/append mode. Flag 9 indicates append, in which case you will be able to add data to your file but not modify file contents. If you want to modify you have to read the entire file into a buffer, modify the buffer and recreate the file with the new contents.

Comment: @gusbro yes i'm using mars. So I should modify the buffer through a store byte instruction and then write it on file with a flag-1?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd do.